# How can I add and remove specific email addresses to and from Outlook's AutoComplete list?

Tags: microsoft-word, autocomplete

My AutoComplete list retains every email address that I input.

1. How do I choose and add  specific addresses to the List?
2. How do I delete   specific (not all) addresses from the List?

Answer (score 1):

From [here](https://support.office.com/en-nz/article/Delete-a-name-from-the-Auto-Complete-list-2e3d8fb1-eefd-4307-ab73-6f2f23164222?ui=en-US&rs=en-NZ&ad=NZ)

**Delete a name from the Auto-Complete list**

The Auto-Complete List is a feature which displays suggestions for names and email addresses as you start to type them in the To, Cc, and Bcc boxes. These suggestions are possible matches from a list of names and email addresses from the email messages that you have sent.

**Auto-Complete list**

There might be entries that you want to remove, such as entries that are no longer current or accurate. To remove unwanted names, do the following:

Select the unwanted name or email address by using the UP ARROW or DOWN ARROW key.

Click  Delete command or press DELETE.

**To remove all names from your Auto-Complete list, do the following:**

Click the File tab.

Click Options.

Click Mail.

Under Send messages, click Empty Auto-Complete List.

To turn off the feature, see [Turn on or off Auto-Complete List name suggestions.](https://support.office.com/en-nz/article/Turn-on-or-off-AutoComplete-List-name-suggestions-7899a2b1-5fbb-486c-b27e-91909a1064f0)

Comment: Thank you, but your answer respectfully doesn't answer my questions. I stated explicitly in my post that 'I do NOT want to empty it'. Also, I asked how to add manually, which your answer doesn't seem to answer.

Comment: @LawArea51Proposal it appears that this answer does explain your first point, how to delete specific emails from the autocomplete list. The bit about clearing it completely is additional information that could be useful to other visitors. Perhaps somebody else will come along with a solution to your second request.