# How can Outlook 2013 stop automatically adding emails, while preserving 'auto-complete'?

Tags: microsoft-outlook-2013

Response to user 'Ƭᴇcʜιᴇ007' 's flag: This does not duplicate [this](https://superuser.com/a/867773/269574).

I intend to keep and preserve MS Outlook 2013's 'auto-complete' feature for email addresses, but I require it only to suggest certain emails of my choice. The problem: Outlook 2013 seems to store and suggest every single email that I ever input into the 'Send' field.

Comment: It's the same question though, just asked without bullet points...

Comment: To others, this looks like the same question.  If you think it's not, there are some nuances that are clear to you but nobody else.  1) Does the answer on the other question solve the problem?  If not, describe the shortcoming.  2)  Edit this question to clarify how it is different from the other question.  Nobody will be able to give you a different answer unless they know how what you want is different.

Answer (score 0):

You can't prevent items from ending up in the AutoComplete list, but you can control what stays in the list. The instructions below work to remove unwanted entries from the list.

**How to remove AutoComplete list entries one at a time**

To remove entries from the AutoComplete cache one entry at a time, follow these steps:

- Open a new email message.
- Type the first few characters of the
  AutoComplete entry that you want to remove.
- When the entry appears in
  the list of suggested names, move your mouse pointer over the name
  until it becomes highlighted, but do not click the name.
- When the "X"
  icon appears next to the highlighted name, click X to remove the name
  from the list, or press the Delete key on the keyboard.

[image]

Source: https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/2199226

Comment: Thanks. Would you please elucidate whether I must remove each unneeded email manually and individually, if I need it not anymore needing it after writing one email?

Comment: Yes. You must remove them manually and individually.

Comment: How inconvenient, but thank you. +.1. Please allow me to postpone acceptation  to encourage other answers, but I shall soon accept if none arises.