# How can Outlook accept, into its Auto-Complete List, only those email addresses that I authorise?

Tags: microsoft-outlook

Abbreviate Auto-Complete List to ACL. I use Outlook 2016.

The ACL ought add only emails that I authorise to be recorded in it. How do I stop Outlook from automatically admitting into the ACL any email address that I type in the 'Sender' field?

It's too inefficient:

1. for Outlook  to ask me each time whether an email address should be admitted.
2. to delete manually [each unsought email](https://superuser.com/a/867773/269574), [suggested here too](https://superuser.com/a/981027/269574).

Answer (score 0):

This is not currently possible with Outlook 2013. You either turn on Auto Complete List (ACL), or turn it off. If you have ACL turned on, ACL will suggest contacts you want to e-mail. If you choose to use ACL and want a pruned list, it has to be done manually.

What you want is currently not a feature in Outlook 2013. Rather than banging your head here trying to figure out a solution, you might try [url=contacting Microsoft for an enhancement request](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/lcris/2008/02/07/how-to-request-features-in-microsoft-products/) to the product.

If you are okay with pruning your contacts list, [NK2Edit by NirSoft](http://www.nirsoft.net/utils/outlook_nk2_edit.html) is a tool no one has mentioned yet. It is a free and lets you edit the ACL list. If you sort by Record Weight ascending, your least common entries will be at the top. You can delete these rows safely. You are free to use any other criteria you wish. I found this way to be an effective way to prune my ACL.